# Apply operation element wise to all lists in nested list

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, nested-lists

I have nested, list for example:

```
[[1.0, 2.0, 3.0],  
 [3.0, 3.0, 3.0]]
```

What I need:

```
[2.0, 2.5, 3.0]
```

So that every element of resulting list is an avarage of lists of nested list by column.

What is the most efficient way to do it in Python 2.7. I guess the solution would invole using map, but i can`t see prorper way to apply it for this task.

Comment: Consider [numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35728138/674039)

Comment: @wim overkill for such a trivial task

Comment: Use `zip` and `map`

Comment: For simple cases, you can just do `[(a + b) / 2.0 for a, b in zip(lists[0], lists[1])]`, or if there are many sublists and not just two, `[sum(a)/float(len(a)) for a in zip(*lists)]` (here `lists` is your nested lists, e.g. `[[1, 2, 3], [3, 3, 3]]`).

Comment: do you really want the integers as ints and the floats as floats? this is not smart, demaning `[2.0, 2.5, 3.0]` would be better (and trivial, e.g. `[(x+y)/2. for x,y in zip(*lst)]`

Comment: @wim transpose won't calculate the average

Comment: @MarcoBonelli: Overkill for *one* trivial task, but if the program involves much more numerical work, NumPy would be a good idea. (Also, the questioner's [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53239103/numpy-2d-array-extrude) is a NumPy question.)

Comment: This question is on fire haha

Comment: At least 2 of the answers on the marked dup clearly deal with 2.7 vs 3.x solutions. Note 2.7 will soon no longer be officially supported. I suggest you upgrade.

Comment: @user2357112 what does that even mean lol. Treat each question separately as it should be. Numpy serves no purpose at all in the scope of this question, it only makes the job heavier by requiring an enormous library.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli, SO answers can and *should* handle edge cases (e.g. big data vs small data). This is why more than one answer is permitted for a question, and why questions don't "close" when a solution is accepted. That aside, this is a dup, and the dup has Python and NumPy answers.

Comment: @jpp well, I guess we can all agree on that. GG on that gold list badghe tho! Ahah.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli: It means that a program that involves *one* simple numerical task may not benefit from NumPy, but a program composed of a thousand simple numerical tasks could benefit greatly. If you say "don't use NumPy" for each individual task without considering what the rest of the program might look like, you end up with a number-crunching program that's 5 times longer and 100 times slower than it would have been with the proper tools.

Comment: @wim woah, ok then.

Comment: I guess you guys are right that numpy is more efficient for a large dataset by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the library 'numpy' for very efficient computations.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1,2,3], [3,3,3]])
np.mean(a, axis=0)
```

Comment: Thank you for showing how to actually solve the problem using numpy, rather than just saying 'use numpy'!

Answer (score 2):

Use `zip` and a list comprehension:

```
lists = [[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [3.0, 3.0, 3.0]]
averages = [sum(l)/len(l) for l in zip(*lists)]
```

Comment: Note they said the want some values as integers (not floats), although I doubt they really want this...

Comment: I doubt they realize the difference.

Comment: either way, it's definitely worth pointing out, especially for other readers

Comment: Added a method that performs integer division when necessary.

Comment: @Chris_Rands yeah, sorry, i forgot to meniton i am dealing with floats here

Comment: @takeshi6 Then why does your desired result show integer answers?

Comment: @Barmar Fixed. I am new to python and i wonder if it makes so much difference wether result is float or int in this very question?

Comment: Usually if you're working with floats you stay with floats throughout, because it takes extra work to convert back to integers when necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You can `zip` the list of lists and `map` it to `statistics.mean`:

```
from statistics import mean
list(map(mean, zip(*lst)))
```

This returns:

```
[2, 2.5, 3]
```

Comment: To nitpick, it actually returns `[2.0, 2.5, 3.0]` (so, all are floats)

Comment: I don't really think so. OP is using python 2.7, statistics was added in 3.4.

Comment: @RobBricheno No, `mean` returns an integer when the mean is really an integer.

Comment: People, please don't downvote answers that are correct, just because the OP is using an outdated version of Python. Such answers may still help other readers who are using a current version of the language.

Comment: @wim 2.7 is not outdated. And this answer is actually wrong since the scope of the question does not involve python 3.

Comment: @blhsing I don't know what else to say, I have run your code and it does not give the output you show, it gives all values as floats as I showed in my first comment here.

Comment: @RobBricheno The OP has changed his input after I gave the answer (please refer to the edit history). His original input was a list of integers, so `statistics.mean` would output integers when warranted.

Comment: @RobBricheno Please try the demo yourself (click on the `run` button): https://repl.it/repls/MundaneDifficultFormats

Comment: @blhsing I'm sorry I doubted you! I had my output because I was using python 3.5.1. The behaviour changed between that version and the version in your repl, and the latest version does indeed give the output you claim.

Comment: @RobBricheno Ah I see. I've never tried 3.5 myself so I had no idea. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#zip) and [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#map). Use `zip` to transpose the matrix and then `map` every column to its mean with the help of [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#sum) to sum all the values in the column.

```
values = [[1, 2, 3], [3, 3, 3]]
averages = map(lambda x: sum(x)/float(len(x)), zip(*values))

print averages
```

Output:

```
[2.0, 2.5, 3.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list(map(lambda x,y: (x+y)/2.0, [1, 2, 3], [3, 3, 3]))
```

Output:

```
[2.0, 2.5, 3.0]
```